# How to check whether given string converted to long is EpochMills or not?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang3

Hi Is there any way to check whether the given string is epoch millis or not

The below code from java.time package converts to EpochMillis.

I am looking for isEpochMillis to return a boolean condition.

***Is there any ready made api from apache commons or google guava to check this ? just like isDouble isLong etc...***

```
/**
     * Obtains an instance of {@code Instant} using milliseconds from the
     * epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
     * <p>
     * The seconds and nanoseconds are extracted from the specified milliseconds.
     *
     * @param epochMilli  the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
     * @return an instant, not null
     * @throws DateTimeException if the instant exceeds the maximum or minimum instant
     */
    public static Instant ofEpochMilli(long epochMilli) {
        long secs = Math.floorDiv(epochMilli, 1000);
        int mos = (int)Math.floorMod(epochMilli, 1000);
        return create(secs, mos * 1000_000);
    }
```

Comment: Huh? Any integer is a valid timestamp. Zero is the epoch itself. Minus a billion billion billion is... quite a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Any positive whole number is theoretically valid. You can add constraints based on your own knowledge of the domain. For example: no timestamps in the future, hence all numbers greater than Instant.now().toEpochMillis() are invalid.

Comment: I know these things, I just need ready made api with apache commons or guava to check whether passed long is parsable or not

Comment: Is there any ready made api from apache commons or google guava to check this ?

Comment: AFAIK no, as mentioned in other comments you have Long.parseLong to verify that the string is a number, and then compare it with Instant.now(). This can be easily wrapped in a utility class in your project.

Answer (score 0):

As the javadoc says, epochMilli is number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01. All long values  are valid epochMillis. It comes down to down to which dates you allow. That will then be your range.

-2 would result in **1969-12-31T23:59:59.998**Z.

Comment: I know these things, I just need ready made api with apache commons or guava to check whether passed long is parsable or not

Comment: Then use `Long.parse(epochMillisInString, 10)`

Comment: Is there any ready made api from apache commons or google guava to check this ?

Comment: If you really want to use for example Apache Commons, you could use NumberUtils.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html